# How to stop searching gps pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, android-pendingintent

I am using location manager class to search current location.

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
i = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 9, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
mLocationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                pi);
mLocationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, pi);
```

When user is indoor my app keep searching for GPS for infinite time. I have also tried canceling pending intent but its not working.